# Do I need to prove a function between two topological spaces $X, Y$ is onto to prove it induces a function on $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

If there is a mapping $f: X\to Y$ between two topological spaces and $X$ has a topology $T_X$ then $Y$ will have a topology $T_f$ induced by $X$ and function $f$. But recently I got confused by something my teacher said while explaining identification functions:

> "If I have a mapping from $X$ to $Y$ and $X$ has a topology and if I were able to prove the mapping was onto then I can say there is a topology $T_f$ induced on $Y$ by $T_X$ and $f$ and then we can complete our prove for identification function".

So my question is, why do I need the function to be onto in order to have an induced topology on $Y$? Now I know I need onto condition to prove identification function but I am asking for the induced topology itself why do i need onto condition for that?

Comment: There is no need of surjectivity in order to define $\tau_f$, but it is convenient since if $y \in Y \setminus f(X)$ then $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \varnothing \in \tau_X$, that is, $\{y\} \in \tau_f$. In other words, $Y \setminus f(X)$ has only isolated points.

Comment: But does f need to be continuous to generate a topology Tf on Y or its  not necessary?

Comment: First, it does not make sense to say if $f$ is continuous or not, since $Y$ is only set and not a topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it is not necessary to have a surjective function to define a topology on the codomain of $f$, but it is sufficient to have one. Indeed, if you have a function $f : (X, \tau) \rightarrow Y$ that is onto, then it induces on $Y$ a topology that is called *quotient topology*, where the open sets are defined in the following way:

> Def: A set $B \subseteq Y$ is said to be open in $Y$ if $f^{-1}(B)$ is
> an open set in $X$.

Now you can see that if $f$ is not surjective, then you may have some $y \in Y$ for which $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is the empty set, so open in $X$ by definition. Hence, these singletons result open in the topology induced by $f$ on $Y$ and you may want to avoid this (just as an example, if you assume more structure on the topology like to be $T_1$, then these sets would be both open and closed, hence the space would result always disconnected by these isolated points).

Comment: thankyou for your answer but I want to ask if by quotient topology you mean identification topology ? because from the definition it sounds the same.

Comment: Yes! It is another waty to call it.

Comment: You were interested in the topology generated by a surjective function that is the quotient topology, but note the same reasoning can be done when $f$ is injective. It originates the subspace topology in the domain, starting from a topology in the codomain. Indeed every time I have an injective function I can include one space into the other. Finally, if $f$ is bijective, then the topology induced on the other set is the same and the function becomes an homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see why surjectivity of the function is involved is that if you have a function $$f:X \rightarrow Y$$ you can form an *equivalence relation* given by the function identifying $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$. Then you see immediately that it is an equivalence relation and so you can form the quotient set $X /\sim$ and so you have the projection onto the quotient that is a surjective function $\pi : X \rightarrow X /\sim$.

As Hitman Reborn correctly pointed out, this is sufficient to define the identification topology via its definition. Nevertheless, note that to have a surjective function is not necessary; it only gives a natural definition to induce a topology on the quotient set, that is to define a topology on it that *makes the projection map continuous.*